# Disable indoor view of buildings in Google Street View Image API

Tags: google-api, google-street-view

I'm using [Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/intro) (**not** the Javascript API) to construct a URL which returns a street view image. The problem is, that sometimes it returns an image of the inside of the building, rather than the image of the building at the provided address. I know this can be disabled using the Javascript API, but can it be disabled via a URL parameter in the Image API?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm facing the same problem on Android.

Comment: @StackExchanger No, but I will be re-tackling the problem next week. I'll post here if I figure it out.

Comment: @Cellydy you should offer a bounty =)

Comment: @Cellydy no news is bad news?

Comment: @TedTaylorofLife No luck :(

Comment: @StackExchanger No luck :(

Comment: There is a feature request for this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826865. Feel free to star it.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `&source=outdoor` as an url parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can make a call to the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) in order to get the lat/lang coordinates to an address.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=400x400&address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&fov=90&heading=235&pitch=10&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Then the you use the `results.geometry.location` from the response to get the coordinates you need to create the Street View Image URL

The Geocoder will always give you a location outside at the entrance, other APIs like Directions API may give you the same indoor problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [Google Street View Image Metadata API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/metadata) to get the copyright info of the image. If this is not equal to "© Google, Inc.", it's a real streetview image.

I know that it's not the best solution, but it works.